# Yii2 and .htaccess redirect 301 from /index.php with or without querystring (/index.php?r=xxxxxx) to just / (root)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii2

I'm using Yii2 and pretty URLs and they are working fine. The problem is all the ugly URLs are also available and Bing is indexing some pages with the index.php and some others with querystring as well. How do I prevent this? How can I redirects from /index.php with or without querystring (/index.php?r=xxxxxx) to just / (root) in htaccess.

I've seen many solutions here and around the web but none of them work for me.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up apache configuration like in yii2 guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-apache-configuration

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For better understanding, please, try it with the default yii2 installation and with pretty Urls enabled. You will notice the "example.com/about" is working as expected, but the "example.com/index.php?r=about" is also available (although not showing the about page, the homepage is shown instead). I would like to disable any querystring (404) or to redirect it, in this example, to "example.com/about". That is my problem (or Bing problem)